# How can I create a task list that updates automatically based on date?

Tags: web-apps, scheduling

I am currently following a schedule of reviewing one book per day, but sometimes get behind schedule, and would like to know how many books behind schedule I am by simply looking at an online program that lets me know what I have yet to do based on me marking complete what I have done (like clicking a button that says 'complete' or 'dismiss') when I complete it, having all tasks uncompleted on one screen up to today's task. I have no ability to download anything nor money to pay for anything.

If how I worded any of this is not understandable, please feel free to ask me for clarification.